# Simple way to group heavy data in xslt 1.0 using non Muenchian grouping

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, grouping, hierarchical-data

I am a total newbie on xslt, and hence unable to understand the complicated solutions provided here for what I want to achieve. Grouping of a heavy data structure ( meaning there are lots of attributes and elements and hence cannot be going with any concatenated solution) in a non Muenchian way. Coz I feel concatenation of large data will hit performance. Here is my sample input data, required output and xsl I have tried :

### # input xml #

```
    <out:OuterSegment>
        <out:Segment >
             <out:from Code="CHN"/>
             <out:tothis Code="HYD"/>
             <out:group>0</out:group>
        </out:Segment>
        <out:Segment >
             <out:from Code="HYD"/>
             <out:tothis Code="BLR"/>
             <out:group>1</out:group>
        </out:Segment>
        <out:Segment >
             <out:from Code="BLR"/>
             <out:tothis Code="TVN"/>
             <out:group>2</out:group>
        </out:Segment>
        <out:Segment >
             <out:from Code="TVN"/>
             <out:tothis Code="DEL"/>
             <out:group>2</out:group>
        </out:Segment>
    </out:OuterSegment>
```

### output xml

```
    <out2:OuterSegment>
        <out2:Segment >
             <out2:from Code="CHN"/>
             <out2:tothis Code="HYD"/>
             <out2:group>0</out2:group>
        </out2:Segment>
    </out2:OuterSegment>    
    <out2:OuterSegment>
        <out2:Segment >
             <out2:from Code="HYD"/>
             <out2:tothis Code="BLR"/>
             <out2:group>1</out2:group>
        </out2:Segment>
    </out2:OuterSegment>
    <out2:OuterSegment>
        <out2:Segment >
             <out2:from Code="BLR"/>
             <out2:tothis Code="TVN"/>
             <out2:group>2</out2:group>
        </out2:Segment>
    </out2:OuterSegment>
    <out2:OuterSegment>
        <out2:Segment >
             <out2:from Code="TVN"/>
             <out2:tothis Code="DEL"/>
             <out2:group>2</out2:group>
        </out2:Segment>
    </out2:OuterSegment>
```

### XSL snippet

```
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
         <xsl:message> its the first row </xsl:message>
         <out:OuterSegment>            
                <xsl:apply-templates select="in2:IncomingSegment"
                                                    mode="localIncomingSegmentRefToSegment" />
            </out:OuterSegment>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:variable name="prevgroup" select="//in2:IncomingSegment[position() - 1]/@Group"/>
         <xsl:message> is the subsequent row</xsl:message>
         <xsl:if test="$prevgroup = //in2:IncomingSegment[$prevgroup]/@Group">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="in2:IncomingSegment"
                                                    mode="localIncomingSegmentRefToSegment" />                      
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="$prevgroup != //in2:IncomingSegment[$prevgroup]/@Group">
                <out:OuterSegment>     
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="in2:IncomingSegment"
                                                    mode="SegmentRefToSegment" />
                </out:OuterSegment>
         </xsl:if>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

I will need to mention that the above input xml was generated by another xslt for which the input is as :

### Actual input xml

```
    <in:RefSegment key="1" group="0">
        <in:inSegment >
             <in:from Code="CHN"/>
             <in:tothis Code="HYD"/>
        </in:inSegment>
    </in:RefSegment>
    <in:RefSegment key="2" group="1">
        <in:inSegment >
             <in:from Code="HYD"/>
             <in:tothis Code="BLR"/>
        </in:inSegment>
    </in:RefSegment>
    <in:RefSegment key="3" group="2">
        <in:inSegment >
             <in:from Code="BLR"/>
             <in:tothis Code="TVN"/>
        </in:inSegment>
    </in:RefSegment>
    <in:RefSegment key="4" group="2">
        <in:inSegment >
             <in:from Code="TVN"/>
             <in:tothis Code="BLR"/>
        </in:inSegment>
    </in:RefSegment>
    <in:DataSegments>
        <in:Data >
                    <in:keyref> 0 </in:keyref>
        </in:Data>
        <in:Data >
            <in:keyref> 1 </in:keyref>
        </in:Data>
        <in:Data >
                <in:keyref> 2 </in:keyref>
        </in:Data>
            <in:Data >
                <in:keyref> 2 </in:keyref>
        </in:Data>
  <in:DataSegments>
```

Is it possible to obtain the final output.xml in one shot out of the above actual input.xml  ?

Comment: It would help if you could explain the **logic** behind the transformation. I don't see any grouping in the result: you start with 4 segments and end up with the same 4 segments, with no data added to them (AFAICS). -- Note also that both your inputs are not well-formed: no root element, and prefixes unbound to a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you handle the namespaces for the input and output xml regarding the `in` and `out2` prefixes and if the namespaces are a matter of concern, so maybe this approach isn't useful but I wanted to share the idea.
This is based on the assumption that all
`<in:Data>` nodes are at a position corresponding to the `<in:RefSegment>` as your actual input XML suggests  - if this is not the case, please add this to your question as then it would be necessary to group by the value of the  `group` attribute of the `<in:RefSegment>` and the corresponding  `<in:keyref>` value.

As adjustment for the input XML snippet I wrapped the `<in:RefSegment>` nodes in a root node with an example namespace: `<root xmlns:in="http://www.example.com">` and added the example namespaces `xmlns:in="http://www.example.com"` and  `xmlns:out2="http://www.example2.com"` to the stylesheet declaration. Because of the `xmlns:out2` namespace, this namespace is added to each `out2:OuterSegment` node.

Following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:in="http://www.example.com" xmlns:out2="http://www.example2.com"
  exclude-result-prefixes="in" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="in:RefSegment">
    <xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>
     <out2:OuterSegment>
       <out2:Segment>
         <out2:from>
           <xsl:attribute name="Code">
             <xsl:value-of select="in:inSegment/in:from/@Code" />
           </xsl:attribute>
         </out2:from>
         <out2:tothis Code="HYD">
            <xsl:attribute name="Code">
              <xsl:value-of select="in:inSegment/in:tothis/@Code" />
            </xsl:attribute>
         </out2:tothis>
         <out2:group>
           <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//in:DataSegments/in:Data[$position]/in:keyref)"/>
        </out2:group>
      </out2:Segment>
    </out2:OuterSegment>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="in:DataSegments"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to your actual input XML with adjustment of the missing closing `</in:DataSegments>` produces the following result:

```
<out2:OuterSegment xmlns:out="http://www.example2.com">
  <out2:Segment>
    <out2:from Code="CHN"/>
    <out2:tothis Code="HYD"/>
    <out2:group>0</out2:group>
  </out2:Segment>
</out2:OuterSegment>
<out2:OuterSegment xmlns:out="http://www.example2.com">
  <out2:Segment>
    <out2:from Code="HYD"/>
    <out2:tothis Code="BLR"/>
    <out2:group>1</out2:group>
  </out2:Segment>
</out2:OuterSegment>
<out2:OuterSegment xmlns:out="http://www.example2.com">
  <out2:Segment>
    <out2:from Code="BLR"/>
    <out2:tothis Code="TVN"/>
    <out2:group>2</out2:group>
  </out2:Segment>
</out:OuterSegment>
<out:OuterSegment xmlns:out="http://www.example2.com">
   <out2:Segment>
     <out2:from Code="TVN"/>
     <out2:tothis Code="BLR"/>
     <out2:group>2</out2:group>
   </out2:Segment>
</out2:OuterSegment>
```

The template matching `in:RefSegment` nodes `<xsl:template match="in:RefSegment">` generates the `<out2:OuterSegment>` nodes. The `<xsl:variable name="position" select="position()"/>` is the position of the current in:RefSegment.
The attributes for the generated `out2:from` and `out2:tothis` nodes are retrieved from the currently processed `in:RefSegment`:

```
<out2:from>
   <xsl:attribute name="Code">
        <xsl:value-of select="in:inSegment/in:from/@Code" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</out2:from>
```

and the value for the `out2:group` retrieved from the `in:Data` node that is at the same position:

```
<out2:group>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(//in:DataSegments
                        /in:Data[$position/in:keyref)"/>
</out2:group>
```

with an additional `normalize-space()` to remove the space that's in the input.
The template matching `in:DataSegments` `<xsl:template match="in:DataSegments"/>` is empty so the `in:DataSegments` node is removed from the output.

Comment: I should have mentioned all customised since my actual xmls have much more attributes and elements. The <in:Data > & the <in:DataSegments> are siblings and that not all elements in context are not children of the same parent node.

Comment: Using for-each-group is could get this done. Did not realize that xslt 1.0 supports forward compatibility, since for-each-group is a xslt 2.0 feature. Thanks Mathaias.